# Storing Database Password

Tags: database, security, database-design, password-hash, secure-coding

If I save the password to the database as a hash in the configuration file of the application or in the code for security reasons, how does the application connect to the database if it does not accept authentication using a hash?
What is the process of authentication if the password is saved as a hash and not cleartext?

Thanks.

tried to search over the internet but didn't find any answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

## Password hashing

Password hashing is used by applications that directly authenticate users. They hash the input coming from the user, and compare it to the hashed version they have on file. That way, they can see if the *user* knows the password, without actually having to know the password *themselves*.

The advantage is that, if a hacker gets full access to the application, and all of its secrets, the user's passwords will not be among them. Instead, the hacker will get a list of hash values, which are more or less useless.

## Database credentials

This is a different situation, because the *database* is doing the authentication, and you're just *storing* your credentials, unhashed, so you can give them to the database later on in the future.

It's risky to store your credentials in plaintext.

So the mysql database has an alternative:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-using-files.html

...and most other databases do, too.

If something like this is not an option, you should at minimum set the permissions on the configuration file to be extremely narrow, so that only you and the database can access your credentials.

### Why couldn't you use a hash to authenticate with the database?

The hash isn't considered secure. A hacker might know a hash, *without* knowing the actual password. The database requires the full password to safeguard the sensitive data.

Likewise, if you're building your own application, you *also* require the user to provide the full, original password. At that point, you would then hash the password to check that the password is correct.

Comment: hey. thanks for answer.
for the application to work she needs to talk to the db so the user and password that the application uses need to be stored in a place that the app knows and authenticate to the db.
but for security reasons, the password stored as a hash so how the application knows what is the password to the database? the database doesnt allow to authenticate with hash

Comment: Right, you can't use a hash to access the database. You'll need to store the original password. If you don't have it, you'll need to get it.

Comment: Just for clarity: There's no way to reverse a hash. It's a one-way process that destroys the original secret. So you'll have to find the original password.

Comment: thank you.
i have read some articles about storing database creds in apps conf for the application user.
the recommendation is to store in hash, but how the application knows how to connect to the database in the password is in hash? what am i missing?

Comment: That's the "Password Hashing" section of my response: The difference is that the application is doing its own authentication.

Comment: When you're doing your own authentication, you can use a hash. When you're storing credentials for a database, you have store the original credentials.

Comment: I've added a section to my response to help explain this.